# JSON response Variable missing during compile time

Tags: android

I am setting up the recyclerview to show some data from the server and this is how my jsonpojo looks alike :

```
public class JSON {

    public class MainCard {
        @SerializedName("Cards")
        public List<Cards> cards;
    }

    public class Cards {
        @SerializedName("Title")
        public String title;
        @SerializedName("Items")
        public List<ItemData> items;
    }

    public class ItemData {
        @SerializedName("Name")
        public String name;
        @SerializedName("Thumb")
        public String thumb;
        @SerializedName("Link")
        public String link;
    }
}
```

and here is the adapter :

```
public class API_Adpater extends RecyclerView.Adapter<API_Adpater.CardsHolder> {
    private List<JSON.ItemData> mlist;
    private List<JSON.Cards> mCards;
    private Context mcontext;

    public API_Adpater(List<JSON.ItemData> mlists, List<JSON.Cards> titles, Context context) {
        this.mlist = mlists;
        this.mcontext = context;
        this.mCards = titles;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CardsHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.singleitems,viewGroup,false);
        return new CardsHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CardsHolder cardsHolder, int i) {
        final JSON.ItemData singleitem = mlist.get(i);
        final JSON.Cards Title = mCards.get(i);
        cardsHolder.textView.setText(Title.title);
        cardsHolder.textView2.setText(singleitem.name);
        cardsHolder.url = singleitem.thumb;
        Glide.with(this.mcontext).load(cardsHolder.url).into(cardsHolder.imageView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mlist.size();
    }

    class CardsHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView textView;
        TextView textView2;
        String url;
        CardsHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            textView2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the mainactivity :

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(APIService.url)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
        Call<JSON.MainCard> call = service.getCards();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<JSON.MainCard>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JSON.MainCard> call, Response<JSON.MainCard> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    JSON.MainCard mainCard = response.body();
                    if (mainCard != null && mainCard.cards !=null) {
                        List<JSON.ItemData> ru = mainCard.cards.items;
// Here on Above Line it can't get the mainCard.Cards.items; it is not showing the `.items` in the code;
                        setupRV(ru);
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Reposnce Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JSON.MainCard> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Check Internet Connectivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void setupRV(List<JSON.ItemData> list) {
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv);
        LinearLayoutManager lm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(lm);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new API_Adpater(list,this));
    }
}
```

On response of retrofit, I need to set the line like 
`List<JSON.ItemData> ru = mainCard.cards.items;`
but it is not working as the codeeditor is not getting the `.items` variable
where is the error?
Can't set the recylcer view.

This is how my json looks alike :

```
{
  "Cards": [
    {
      "Title": "Title",
      "Items": [
        {
          "Name": "Name",
          "Thumb": "Thumb",
          "Link": "link"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Title": "Title",
      "Items": [
        {
          "Name": "Name",
          "Thumb": "Thumb",
          "Link": "link"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And this the error it can't find the `items` from the `maincards.cards`
[image]

I need to set the image from the url and name and title in the recycler view.

Comment: You'll need to make your internal `public classes` **static** i guess.

Comment: Did you check the response from the server and validated you're getting what you expected?

Comment: @JeelVankhede i already did that but it's not working.

Comment: @UdiIdan The error is at design time

Comment: If it's in design time, then what is the error you're getting?

Comment: You can use **getters & setters** for that if you want to.

Comment: @UdiIdan see the question i've added the error.

Comment: @JeelVankhede already did that too but didn't help

Comment: Try invalidate caches and restart

Answer (score 2):

You're accessing items directly on list in this line

```
List<JSON.ItemData> ru = mainCard.cards.items;
```

here cards is a list, that's why you can't access items directly 
Get the object of Cards and then use it

```
List<JSON.ItemData> ru  = mainCard.cards.get(index).items;
```

Based on your requirements
you need to iterate over

```
if (mainCard != null && mainCard.cards !=null) {
        List<JSON.ItemData> ru = new ArrayList();
        for(Cards itemCard : mainCard.cards)
        {
            ru.addAll(itemCard.items);
        }
                setupRV(ru);
}
```

Comment: Please checkout my adapter. the position thing is being done in the adapter and here i need to send the list as it is. Checking the adpater may help you to find the bug. and here the i can't set the index.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
 List<MoviesApi.ItemData> ru = mainCard.cards.getItems();
```

Comment: there is no getter and setters, however iv'e already tried with the getter and setters. but it didn't helped.

Answer (score 0):

Make separate class for each model as below.

```
-----------------------------------com.example.Card.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Card {

@SerializedName("Title")
@Expose
public String title;
@SerializedName("Items")
@Expose
public List<Item> items = null;

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Item.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Item {

@SerializedName("Name")
@Expose
public String name;
@SerializedName("Thumb")
@Expose
public String thumb;
@SerializedName("Link")
@Expose
public String link;

}
-----------------------------------com.example.MainCard.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class MainCard {

@SerializedName("Cards")
@Expose
public List<Card> cards = null;

}
```

To create these pojos I used this site http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/